# Program cannot load shared library GCC

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

First things first, here is the error message:
`./Game: error while loading shared libraries: libEngine.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

There was no problems while compiling.

Library directories passed to GCC while compiling Game: `-L../../bin -L.`

Directory tree:

`ENGINE
-bin
--Game (executable)
--libEngine.so
-Game
--src
---source code + Game makefile
-Engine
--src
---source code + shared library makefile`

I can provide more info on demand.

Comment: What are all the flags you're passing to GCC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a possible, but usually not the best solution. In particular, dependence on environment produces programs which work for you, but not for your coworkers or your professor (because their environment is different).

Adding `-rpath=/path/to/bin` to the link line eliminates the need to muck with environment.

Even better: `-rpath='$ORIGIN'` lets you move the entire installation directory to a different place, and the program will still find its shared libraries in its own `bin/` directory.

Comment: @fedqx It would be best to ask a separate question (asking is free :-). You should also say *which* part of the template you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!